# run function everytime endpoint is hit in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hey how can make an API in next.js run a function each time i hit an endpoint so i can generate random values?
Right now everytime i go to /api it gives me same number.

I am reading the documentation but it does not mention this situation.
When i search stackoverflow for "run function when endpoint is hit next.js" i dont get anything either, so bear with me on this probably simple question.

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random(10));
  res.status(200).json({ name: number });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.random()
```

always returns between 0 and 1.
use

```
Math.random() * 10
```

instead.